# Add value to a variable from another variable?

Tags: php

these are two variables with two different values.

```
$variableone = 'This';
$variabletwo = 'Place';
```

How do I add variable to to variable one like this with a empty space between "This" and "Place":

```
$variableone = 'This Place';
```

and how do i update variable two to have no value like this

```
$variabletwo = " ";
```

I would apperciate a answer thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use string concatenation

```
$variableone = 'This';
$variabletwo = 'Place';
$variableone .= (" " . $variabletwo);
$variabletwo = " ";
```

or string substitution

```
$variableone = 'This';
$variabletwo = 'Place';
$variableone = "$variableone $variabletwo";
$variabletwo = " ";
```